# how to know user stopped typing in text field() to call search api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, search, searchbar, flutter-textformfield

I want to stop searching for every words in `onchanged()` `textfield` and also tried  `searchdelete` same action happening here . so I want to search in set of words or  when stop typing. and call api request
Any other way to search

Comment: How about `onSubmitted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to onSubmitted or onEditingComplete

> `onSubmitted` → ValueChanged?
> Called when the user indicates that they are done editing the text in the field. [...]
> final

> The `onEditingComplete` callback also runs when the user finishes editing. It's different from onSubmitted because it has a default value which updates the text controller and yields the keyboard focus. Applications that require different behavior can override the default onEditingComplete callback.

Comment: Thank you, but it is working when user click done button , i want like auto complete search show suggestion

Comment: In textfield you have an option named enableSuggestions. Set it to true. Then if the user clicks on that suggestion it will trigger on submitted

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, you can achieve a callback when the user finishes typing in a text field by using a combination of the TextField widget, a TextEditingController, and a delay mechanism. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

Import the necessary packages:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
Create a TextEditingController to control the text field and listen for changes in the text:
```

```dart
final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

Create a callback function that will be called when typing finishes. You can use a Timer to delay the callback. Here, we'll use a 500 milliseconds delay as an example:

```dart
Timer? _debounceTimer;

void _onTypingFinished(String text) {
  if (_debounceTimer != null) {
    _debounceTimer!.cancel();
  }

  _debounceTimer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    // Call your callback function here
    print('Typing finished: $text');
  });
}
```

Create a TextField widget and set the controller to _textEditingController to control the text field's value. Also, add an onChanged callback to listen for changes in the text field:

```dart
TextField(
  controller: _textEditingController,
  onChanged: _onTypingFinished,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Type something...',
  ),
)
```

In this example, _onTypingFinished is called whenever the text in the text field changes. However, it uses a debounce mechanism to delay the actual callback by 500 milliseconds. This allows you to perform an action only when the user pauses typing for the specified duration.

You can replace the print statement inside _onTypingFinished with your custom logic to perform any desired actions when typing finishes.

Remember to dispose of the _textEditingController when you're done with the widget to avoid memory leaks:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  _textEditingController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

This way, you can get a callback when typing finishes in a Flutter text field with a debounce mechanism to control the delay before the callback is triggered.